# Preventing chained callbacks from switching dropdown to original value dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a lengthy section of code for several chained callbacks that stem from a multiple nested dictionary. I have all of the necessary dropdowns and options that I would like to provide. However, whenever I change the 'crop' dropdown in this example to something other than the original option (which is corn) it resets the 'Weighting' dropdown below. Similarly, if I change the 'Weighting' dropdown, it resets the 'Forecast Variable' dropdown to the original option. How can I prevent this? The point of the chained callbacks was so that changing one option would change the data that is plotted, as they are all linked.

I don't think the data is important here? But it functions like this:

```
final_dict[init_date][model][weight][crop]
```

The above exact dictionary then would output a dataframe. The columns in the dataframe then would be the 'forecast variable' which will eventually be plotted. If I do need to add data I can try and do that but the dict is VERY big.

Here is the code I have so far. Notice that the graph is empty because I haven't gotten that far yet.

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, ClientsideFunction
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
import glob
import datetime as dt

import xarray as xr
import os 
from PIL import Image
import time
import random

my_dict={}

for i in np.arange(1,17,1):
    n=random.randint(1,10)
    m=random.randint(1,10)
    data=[[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-06'),n,m],[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-07'),m,n],[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-08'),n,m],[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-09'),m,n]]
    my_dict[i]=pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['time', 'Temp','Precip'])

final_dict={'day1':{'model1':{'weight1':{'crop1':my_dict[1], 'crop2':my_dict[2]},
                           'weight2':{'crop1':my_dict[3], 'crop2':my_dict[4]}},
                 
                 'model2':{'weight1':{'crop1':my_dict[5], 'crop2':my_dict[6]},
                           'weight2':{'crop1':my_dict[7], 'crop2':my_dict[8]}}},
         
         'day2':{'model1':{'weight1':{'crop1':my_dict[9], 'crop2':my_dict[10]},
                           'weight2':{'crop1':my_dict[11], 'crop2':my_dict[12]}},
                 
                 'model2':{'weight1':{'crop1':my_dict[13], 'crop2':my_dict[14]},
                           'weight2':{'crop1':my_dict[15], 'crop2':my_dict[16]}}}}

app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])

controls = dbc.Card(
    [   dbc.FormGroup(
            [dbc.Label("Init Date"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='init_dd',
                    options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in final_dict.keys()],
                    value=list(final_dict.keys())[0],
                    clearable=False,
                ),
            ]
        ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [dbc.Label("Model"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='model_dd',
                    clearable=False,
                ),
            ]
        ), 
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [dbc.Label("Crop"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='crop_dd',
                    clearable=False,
                ),
            ]
        ),           
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [dbc.Label("Weighting"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='weight_dd',
                    clearable=False,
                ),
            ]
        ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [dbc.Label("Forecast Variable"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='columns_dd',
                    clearable=False,
                ),
            ]
        ),

    ],
    body=True,
)


app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        html.Hr(),
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col(controls)
                ],  align="start"), 
            ],xs = 2)
            ,
            dbc.Col([
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col([html.Div(id = 'plot_title')],)
                ]),
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="crop-graph")),
                ])
            ])
        ],), 
    ],
    fluid=True,
)
    
# Callbacks #####################################################################
#set the model
@app.callback(
    Output('model_dd', 'options'),
    [Input('init_dd', 'value')])
def set_model_options(model):
    return [{'label': i.replace('_',' '), 'value': i} for i in final_dict[model]]
 
@app.callback(
    Output('model_dd', 'value'),
    [Input('model_dd', 'options')])
def set_model_options_value(available_model):
    return available_model[0]['value']

#set the weight
@app.callback(
    Output('weight_dd', 'options'),
    [Input('init_dd', 'value'),
     Input('model_dd', 'value')])
def set_weight_options(selected_init, selected_model):
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in final_dict[selected_init][selected_model]]
 
@app.callback(
    Output('weight_dd', 'value'),
    [Input('weight_dd', 'options')])
def set_weight_value(available_weight):
    return available_weight[0]['value']

#set the crop
@app.callback(
    Output('crop_dd', 'options'),
    [Input('init_dd', 'value'),
     Input('model_dd', 'value'),
     Input('weight_dd', 'value')])
def set_crop_options(selected_init, selected_model, selected_weight):
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in final_dict[selected_init][selected_model][selected_weight]]
 
@app.callback(
    Output('crop_dd', 'value'),
    [Input('crop_dd', 'options')])
def set_crop_value(available_crop):
    return available_crop[0]['value']

#set the variable
@app.callback(
    Output('columns_dd', 'options'),
    [Input('init_dd', 'value'),
     Input('model_dd', 'value'),
     Input('weight_dd', 'value'),
     Input('crop_dd', 'value')])
def set_column_options(selected_init, selected_model, selected_weight, selected_crop):
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in final_dict[selected_init][selected_model][selected_weight][selected_crop].columns[1:]]
 
@app.callback(
    Output('columns_dd', 'value'),
    [Input('columns_dd', 'options')])
def set_column_value(available_column):
    return available_column[1]['value']

app.run_server(mode='external', port = 8099)
```

Edit: Added in sample dummy data. Notice how when changing certain combinations of options, other options switch back to the original value. Would like to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Good question, and good that the code is complete. It would probably be easier to also others to make use of this question later if the code was shorter. Could you try to reduce the code to absolute minimum what is needed to reproduce the error?

Comment: @np8 cut it down some. Hope that's enough. Think everything else is needed.

Comment: To manage callback flows, I find it useful to create hidden user data https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks and gather various user-inputs and their condition assessments and then pass it to another hidden data (as an Output of a callback). Then this can serve as a triggering Input to the main calculation callback (so the point of triggering is just one signal).  This way, you create intermediate result(s) and use them as Input(s) to subsequent Callback. Think of creating a flowchart with various input-check conditions in various places. Having intermediate inputs will help.

Comment: @KM_83 Not sure I quite understand what you're getting at here. In my example, since everything comes from a multiple nested dictionary, changing one option in any dropdown should change the output of the graph (which I will make eventually). What I don't want is the user to select a couple different options in different dropdowns that aren't the original option and have a different dropdown switch back to the original option. The data they want to display will never actually display then. Just making sure my Q is clear and trying to understand your suggestion.

Comment: if you set `app.run_server(.., debug=True)` you may see the flow chart. Chained callbacks can get triggered all over. Insert print function in each callback and observe which one is called when. You might see the chaining events do not flow as you intended. To streamline those, you could use hidden user-data as intermediate inputs.  Another option is to dynamically return inputs like `dcc.Dropdown( id='model_dd', ..) ` as an Output of your callback given `init_dd`.

Comment: I’m planning on adding a minimal data sample tomorrow so it will be fully runnable.

Comment: I have added sample dummy data and it should be a complete, runnable snippet now.

Comment: @KM_83 I understand your comments now. However, I am struggling to find any examples of 'hidden user data'. Do you have any suggestions here?

Comment: Example 1 of https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks  shows how one can gather user inputs etc. and store them as a json-like intermediate input in hidden div(). And another callback() will use this intermediate input as its input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific data example helped. I see that

- datasets are stored in nested dictionary
- you want to allow the user to select a particular dataset (for which each user-input option depends on the previous/upstream selections in the nested structure).
- Because the nested structure here means that for a given input change, you want to update the input options *only for the subsequent/downstream inputs*.

About your issue with better controlling chained callbacks, I think it's a matter of using `Input()` and `State()` in right places.

Try this (I renamed your `final_dict` so that it is easier to monitor what's going on):

```py
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, ClientsideFunction
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
import glob
import datetime as dt

import xarray as xr
import os 
from PIL import Image
import time
import random

my_dict={}

for i in np.arange(1,17,1):
    n=random.randint(1,10)
    m=random.randint(1,10)
    data=[[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-06'),n,m],[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-07'),m,n],[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-08'),n,m],[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-09'),m,n]]
    my_dict[i]=pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['time', 'Temp','Precip'])

final_dict={'day1':{'model1':{'weight1':{'crop1':my_dict[1], 'cropA':my_dict[2]},
                           'weight2':{'crop2':my_dict[3], 'cropB':my_dict[4]}},
                 
                 'model2':{'weight3':{'crop3':my_dict[5], 'cropC':my_dict[6]},
                           'weight4':{'crop4':my_dict[7], 'cropD':my_dict[8]}}},
         
         'day2':{'model3':{'weight5':{'crop5':my_dict[9], 'cropE':my_dict[10]},
                           'weight6':{'crop6':my_dict[11], 'cropF':my_dict[12]}},
                
                 'model4':{'weight7':{'crop7':my_dict[13], 'cropG':my_dict[14]},
                           'weight8':{'crop8':my_dict[15], 'cropH':my_dict[16]}}}}

app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])

controls = dbc.Card(
    [   dbc.FormGroup(
            [dbc.Label("Init Date"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='init_dd',
                    options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in final_dict.keys()],
                    value=list(final_dict.keys())[0],
                    clearable=False,
                ),
            ]
        ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [dbc.Label("Model"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='model_dd',
                    clearable=False,
                ),
            ]
        ), 
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [dbc.Label("Crop"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='crop_dd',
                    clearable=False,
                ),
            ]
        ),           
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [dbc.Label("Weighting"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='weight_dd',
                    clearable=False,
                ),
            ]
        ),
        dbc.FormGroup(
            [dbc.Label("Forecast Variable"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id='columns_dd',
                    clearable=False,
                ),
            ]
        ),

    ],
    body=True,
)


app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        html.Hr(),
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col(controls)
                ],  align="start"), 
            ],xs = 2)
            ,
            dbc.Col([
                dbc.Row(html.Div(id='selected_data')),
                # dbc.Row([
                #     dbc.Col([html.Div(id = 'plot_title')],)
                # ]),
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="crop-graph")),
                ])                
            ])
        ],), 
    ],
    fluid=True,
)
    
# Callbacks #####################################################################
#set the model
@app.callback(
    Output('model_dd', 'options'),
    [Input('init_dd', 'value')])
def set_model_options(model):
    return [{'label': i.replace('_',' '), 'value': i} for i in final_dict.get(model).keys()]
 
@app.callback(
    Output('model_dd', 'value'),
    [Input('model_dd', 'options')])
def set_model_options_value(available_model):
    return available_model[0]['value']

#set the weight
@app.callback(
    Output('weight_dd', 'options'),
    [Input('model_dd', 'value')],
    [State('init_dd', 'value')])
def set_weight_options(selected_model, selected_init):
    if selected_model is None: return None 
    print('selected_model(): ', selected_init, selected_model)
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in final_dict.get(selected_init).get(selected_model).keys()]
 
@app.callback(
    Output('weight_dd', 'value'),
    [Input('weight_dd', 'options')])
def set_weight_value(available_weight):
    return available_weight[0]['value']

#set the crop
@app.callback(
    Output('crop_dd', 'options'),
     [Input('weight_dd', 'value')],
     [State('init_dd', 'value'),
     State('model_dd', 'value')])
def set_crop_options(selected_weight, selected_init, selected_model):
    if selected_model is None or selected_weight is None: return None 
    print('set_crop_options(): ',selected_init, selected_model, selected_weight)
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in final_dict.get(selected_init).get(selected_model).get(selected_weight).keys()]

@app.callback(
    Output('crop_dd', 'value'),
    [Input('crop_dd', 'options')])
def set_crop_value(available_crop):
    return available_crop[0]['value']

#set the variable
@app.callback(
    Output('columns_dd', 'options'),
    [Input('crop_dd', 'value')],
    [State('init_dd', 'value'),
     State('model_dd', 'value'),
     State('weight_dd', 'value')])
def set_column_options(selected_crop, selected_init, selected_model, selected_weight):
    if selected_crop is None or selected_weight is None or selected_model is None: return None
    print('set_column_options(): ', selected_init, selected_model, selected_weight, selected_crop)
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in final_dict.get(selected_init).get(selected_model).get(selected_weight).get(selected_crop).columns[1:]]
 
@app.callback(
    Output('columns_dd', 'value'),
    [Input('columns_dd', 'options')])
def set_column_value(available_column):
    if available_column is None: return None
    return available_column[1]['value']

@app.callback(
    Output('selected_data', 'children'),
    [Input('init_dd', 'value'),
     Input('model_dd', 'value'),
     Input('weight_dd', 'value'),
     Input('crop_dd', 'value'),
     Input('columns_dd','value')]
    )
def show_data(init_dd, model_dd, weight_dd, crop_dd, columns_dd):
    if crop_dd is None or weight_dd is None or model_dd is None or columns_dd is None: return None
    print('show_data():', init_dd, model_dd, weight_dd, crop_dd, columns_dd)
    try:
        data = final_dict[init_dd][model_dd][weight_dd][crop_dd][columns_dd].to_json(orient='split')
    except:
        return
    return data


def make_plot(df, var):
    fig = go.Figure(
            data=[go.Scatter(x=df['time'], y=df[var], name=var)],
            layout={
                'yaxis': {'title': f'Plot of <b>{var}</b>'}
            }
        )
    return fig


no_data_fig = {"layout": {
        "xaxis": { "visible": False},
        "yaxis": {"visible": False},
        "annotations": [
            { "text": "",
                "xref": "paper",
                "yref": "paper",
                "showarrow": False,
                "font": {"size": 20 }
            }]
        }
    }

@app.callback(
    Output('crop-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('init_dd', 'value'),
     Input('model_dd', 'value'),
     Input('weight_dd', 'value'),
     Input('crop_dd', 'value'),
     Input('columns_dd','value')]
    )
def plot_data(init_dd, model_dd, weight_dd, crop_dd, columns_dd):
    if crop_dd is None or weight_dd is None or model_dd is None or columns_dd is None: return None
    print('plot_data():', init_dd, model_dd, weight_dd, crop_dd, columns_dd)
    try:
        data = final_dict[init_dd][model_dd][weight_dd][crop_dd]
        data_col = data[columns_dd]
    except:
        return no_data_fig
    return make_plot(data, columns_dd)


app.run_server(mode='external', port = 8098, debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for putting effort into this. Unfortunately this still does what I don't want it to do. In my original dict each selectable option is the same after 'model'. This is on purpose so that a user can **theoretically** change one dropdown to easily compare the two back and forth. However, currently that is not possible because changing an upstream option (say weight) changes all of the downstream options to an original, pre-specified option. Does this make sense? My original question could be poorly worded.

Comment: So, I in the other answer I commented out the callback for "column_dd", so that it stays fixed.  If you want fixed options for "weight_dd", just do the same and get rid of the callback.  I thought the point of reactively updating options is that options differ depending on the choice of another input.

Comment: I do want the options to be reactive, but don't want the downstream options to revert to the original value specified in the callback. In my specific example, I want all of the options to be the EXACT same name after the very first option/callback (the data is different though). Say someone has selected 'weight2', but now wants to change the model from 'model1' ---> 'model 2'. Currently, that would force the weight dropdown back to 'weight1', even though the user likely wanted to look at 'model2' and 'weight2'. How can I achieve this?

Comment: After doing some closer looking, maybe your second answer is what I am looking to do. I am not sure if I actually need any of them chained together. I will look more into this and get back on here later to provide an update.

Comment: If you don't need to update options, just give fixed options and don't use callback for updating them. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Alright, so it turns out I never actually needed to chain the callbacks together. I have removed them and it works perfectly as intended. The original question was poorly worded, but I am going to give you credit for posting a solution to my question. Thanks for indirectly helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another version.

- I noticed that you wanted to keep the data column `column_dd` to be fixed without being updated (maybe assumeing the identical columns in the final dataset across different versions). So, I commented out the callback for updating `column_dd`.
- You can also combine outputs as a list.
- I tried to show a way to use dynamic input generation but ended up not needing to dynamically update it (I couldn't specify the same output-id twice, which was inconvenient. I just kept this for a demo, and you don't need to switch to this style.)  Note that it is still possible to use it as a State() in a callback and overwrite its properties).

```py
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, ClientsideFunction
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
import glob
import datetime as dt

import xarray as xr
import os 
from PIL import Image
import time
import random

my_dict={}

for i in np.arange(1,17,1):
    n=random.randint(1,10)
    m=random.randint(1,10)
    data=[[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-06'),n,m],[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-07'),m,n],[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-08'),n,m],[pd.Timestamp('2020-10-09'),m,n]]
    my_dict[i]=pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['time', 'Temp','Precip'])

final_dict={'day1':{'model1':{'weight1':{'crop1':my_dict[1], 'cropA':my_dict[2]},
                           'weight2':{'crop2':my_dict[3], 'cropB':my_dict[4]}},
                 
                 'model2':{'weight3':{'crop3':my_dict[5], 'cropC':my_dict[6]},
                           'weight4':{'crop4':my_dict[7], 'cropD':my_dict[8]}}},
         
         'day2':{'model3':{'weight5':{'crop5':my_dict[9], 'cropE':my_dict[10]},
                           'weight6':{'crop6':my_dict[11], 'cropF':my_dict[12]}},
                
                 'model4':{'weight7':{'crop7':my_dict[13], 'cropG':my_dict[14]},
                           'weight8':{'crop8':my_dict[15], 'cropH':my_dict[16]}}}}

app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])


# Helpers #####################################################################

def get_dict_keys(varlist):
    dic = final_dict
    for var in varlist:
        dic = dic.get(var)
    return dic

def make_options(option_iter):
    return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in option_iter]

class InputContainer:
    def __init__(self, input_dd='day1', model_dd='model1', weight_dd='weight1',
        crop_dd='crop1', columns_dd='Precip'):
        
        self.container = [ 
            dbc.FormGroup(
                [dbc.Label("Init Date"),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='init_dd',
                        options= make_options(final_dict.keys()),
                        value=input_dd,
                        clearable=False,
                    ),
                ]
            ),
            dbc.FormGroup(
                [dbc.Label("Model"),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='model_dd',
                        value = model_dd,
                        clearable=False,
                    ),
                ]
            ), 
            dbc.FormGroup(
                [dbc.Label("Weighting"),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='weight_dd',
                        value = weight_dd,
                        clearable=False,
                    ),
                ]
            ),
            dbc.FormGroup(
                [dbc.Label("Crop"),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='crop_dd',
                        value = crop_dd,
                        clearable=False,
                    ),
                ]
            ),          
            dbc.FormGroup(
                [dbc.Label("Forecast Variable"),
                    dcc.Dropdown(
                        id='columns_dd',
                        value = columns_dd,
                        options = make_options(['time', 'Temp','Precip']),
                        clearable=False,
                    ),
                ]
            ),
        ]
        self.assign_index()

    def assign_index(self): # unused: just for an idea 
        self.idx = {} 
        for i, item in enumerate(self.container): 
            if hasattr(item.children[1], 'id'): # skip the label at 0
                self.idx[item.children[1].id] = i

    def update_options(self, varname, options, selected=0):  # unused: just for an idea 
        pos = self.idx[varname]
        print(self.container[pos].children[1])
        if hasattr(self.container[pos].children[1],'id'):
            setattr(self.container[pos].children[1],'options', options)
            setattr(self.container[pos].children[1],'value', options[selected].get('value'))


# UI #####################################################################
controls = dbc.Card(
    html.Div(
        id='dynamic-input-container',
        children = InputContainer().container),
    body=True,
)


app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        html.Hr(),
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col(controls)
                ],  align="start"), 
            ],xs = 2)
            ,
            dbc.Col([
                dbc.Row(html.Div(id='selected_data')),
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="crop-graph")),
                ])                
            ])
        ],), 
    ], 
    fluid=True,
)
    
# Callbacks #####################################################################

#set the model
@app.callback(
    [Output('model_dd', 'options'),
     Output('model_dd', 'value')],
    [Input('init_dd', 'value')],
    )
def update_model_options(input_dd):
    print('update_model_options():')
    options = make_options(get_dict_keys([input_dd]).keys())
    return options, options[0].get('value')

#set the weight
@app.callback(
    [Output('weight_dd', 'options'),
    Output('weight_dd', 'value')],
    [Input('model_dd', 'value')],
    [State('init_dd', 'value')])
def update_weight_options(model_dd, input_dd):
    print('update_weight_options():')
    options = make_options(get_dict_keys([input_dd, model_dd]).keys())
    return options, options[0].get('value')

#set the crop
@app.callback(
    [Output('crop_dd', 'options'),
    Output('crop_dd', 'value')],
    [Input('weight_dd', 'value')],
    [State('init_dd', 'value'),
     State('model_dd', 'value')])
def update_crop_options(weight_dd, input_dd, model_dd):
    print('update_crop_options():')
    options = make_options(get_dict_keys([input_dd, model_dd, weight_dd]).keys())
    return options, options[0].get('value')

# #set the variable
# @app.callback(
#     [Output('columns_dd', 'options'),
#      Output('columns_dd','value')],
#     [Input('crop_dd', 'value')],
#     [State('init_dd', 'value'),
#      State('model_dd', 'value'),
#      State('weight_dd', 'value')])
# def set_column_options(crop_dd, input_dd, model_dd, weight_dd):
#     print('update_column_options():')
#     options = make_options(get_dict_keys([input_dd, model_dd, weight_dd, crop_dd]).columns[1:])
#     return options, options[0].get('value')

def make_plot(df, var):
    fig = go.Figure(
            data=[go.Scatter(x=df['time'], y=df[var], name=var)],
            layout={
                'yaxis': {'title': f'Plot of <b>{var}</b>'}
            }
        )
    return fig


no_data_fig = {"layout": {
        "xaxis": { "visible": False},
        "yaxis": {"visible": False},
        "annotations": [
            { "text": "",
                "xref": "paper",
                "yref": "paper",
                "showarrow": False,
                "font": {"size": 20 }
            }]
        }
    }

@app.callback(
    Output('crop-graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('init_dd', 'value'),
     Input('model_dd', 'value'),
     Input('weight_dd', 'value'),
     Input('crop_dd', 'value'),
     Input('columns_dd','value')]
    )
def plot_data(init_dd, model_dd, weight_dd, crop_dd, columns_dd):
    if crop_dd is None or weight_dd is None or model_dd is None or columns_dd is None: return None
    print('plot_data():', init_dd, model_dd, weight_dd, crop_dd, columns_dd)
    try:
        data = final_dict[init_dd][model_dd][weight_dd][crop_dd]
        data_col = data[columns_dd]
    except:
        return no_data_fig
    return make_plot(data, columns_dd)


app.run_server(mode='external', port = 8098, debug=True)
```